# PIL edición de imagenes python

Tags: python, imagen

Estoy aprendiendo a usar `PIL`, mi objetivo es pegar una imagen encima de otra para que se quede en un lugar exacto.

> Handicap: Mi servidor elimina el canal *alpha* de las imagenes.

La primera imagen tiene un círculo donde debería haber trasparencia, pero al no tener canal *alpha*, se queda un circulo blanco.

La segunda imagen es rectangular, la idea era pegar esa imagen (fondo de la primera) donde el círculo, de forma que se viera de forma circular directamente.

Al no ser trasparente el círculo, la segunda imagen no se ve.

```py
final = Image.new("RGBA",(1920, 1065),(0,0,0,252))
imagen2 = Image.open("try.png")
imagen1 = Image.open("try2.png")
final.paste(imagen1, (150,100))
final.paste(imagen2, (0,0))
final.show()
final.save("images/final.png")
```

Las 2 soluciones que se me han ocurrido son:

1- Recortar la imagen cuadrada y hacerla redonda y luego pegarla.

2- Seleccionar por color (blanco) y crear el canal alpha en el proceso.
Edit: Lo único blanco de la imagen sería ese círculo, por eso esta opción es válida.

He mirado la documentación de `PIL` pero no he encontrado nada que me ayude en ninguno de los casos, no se como solucionarlo.

Agradecería una ayuda, no necesito el código completo, sino la función. También me serviría otra opción diferente a las 2 que planteo.

Comment: ¿Se puede asumir que lo único blanco de la imagen es el círculo antes transparente? ¿O el radio  centro del mismo?

Comment: Si, la imagen tiene tonos muy oscuros asi que lo único blanco es el circulo antes transparente.

Answer (score 1):

Si estamos en situación de asumir que los únicos pixeles completamente blancos de la imagen son aquellos se corresponden con la transparencia original, una opción muy simple es recurrir a NumPy (el cual ya usa PIL/Pillow por debajo) y realizando un simple slicing modificar el valor del canal alpha a 0 para aquellos pixeles de blanco puro `RGB = (255, 255, 255)`

```
import numpy as np
import PIL

fondo = PIL.Image.open("fondo.png").convert("RGBA")
img = PIL.Image.open("imagen.png").convert("RGBA")
arr = np.array(fondo)
arr[:, :, 3] = (arr[:, :, :3] != 255).any(axis=2) * 255

fondo = PIL.Image.fromarray(arr, mode='RGBA')
img.paste(fondo, (0, 0), fondo)
img.show()
```

- Con `arr[:, :, :3]` seleccionamos solo los valores RGB de cada pixel, ignorando el canal alpha. Luego simplemente comprueba por cada pixel si alguno de los valores RGB es diferente de 255 (`arr[:, :, :3] != 255`). Es decir, si tenemos el pixel:

  ```
  [255, 125, 255, 0] --> [False, True, False]
  [255, 125, 255, 0] --> [False, False, False]
  ```
- Al aplicar `any` lo que conseguimos es que por cada pixel reduzca los tres valores a un único boleano, si alguno de los canales RGB no es 255 el pixel queda con valor `True`, en caso contrario (blanco) queda como `False`.

  ```
  [255, 125, 255, 0] --> [False, True, False]   --> True
  [255, 125, 255, 0] --> [False, False, False]  --> False
  ```
- Ahora solo queda multiplicar el array de boleanos por 255. Si un pixel es `True` (1) quedará con valor alpha 255, si es `False` (0) quedará con valor alpha 0 (transparencia). Teniendo este array con los valores alpha basta con asignarlos a los pixeles de la imagen.

Por ejemplo, para:

**fondo.png:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**image.png:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque muy simple, el problema está en si existen otras regiones blancas en la imagen o si presenta un ruido considerable con pixeles blancos dispersos. En estos casos podríamos recurrir a OpenCv por ejemplo y detectar el círculo blanco de la imagen o áreas blancas de un tamaño mínimo.